# How to set a class function to button onclick?

Tags: javascript

I have two class functions which I want to set to a button on certain actions. I am trying to achieve it like this:

```js
class Button {
    constructor() {
        this.button = document.createElement('div');
        this.button.className = 'button';
        this.setPlayingState();
        document.body.appendChild(this.button);
        return this.button;
    }
    setPlayingState() {
        this.button.setAttribute('onclick', 'this.pause()');
        console.log('playing');
    }
    setPausedState() {
        this.button.setAttribute('onclick', 'this.play()');
        console.log('paused');
    }
    play() {
        // ...
    }
    pause() {
        // ...
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    let button = new Button();
}
```

```css
.button {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.pause is not a function at HTMLDivElement.onclick

Comment: In constructor this.button.onclick = this.setState() and do both logics in this function

Comment: That solves it. Thanks.

Comment: @MujnoiGyulaTamas, It seems that your suggestion solved OP's problem, you should add it in answer so OP can accept it.

Comment: I'll add a complet answer once I get to a PC :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pause or a play function with this as parameter and will do the same thing like this it will create the same effect and also change
this.pause() to pause()
this.play() to play()

```
pause(elem){
//code
}

play(elem){
//code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `addEventListener` instead of `this.button.setAttribute('onclick', 'this.pause()');`. Also note that `callback` function will be assigned with `this.pause`. Do not wrap it with `''` or don't call it with `this.pause()`.

As comment from @Mujnoi Gyula Tamas, assigning event should be done at `constructor` else it will `assigned` multiple times and will produce incorrect behavior. So use `this.button.addEventListener('click', this.setState.bind(this));`.

Added new `function` as `setState` and used `state` `attribute` to `get/set` current state.

```js
class Button {
  constructor() {
    this.button = document.createElement('div');
    this.button.className = 'button';
    this.setPlayingState();
    document.body.appendChild(this.button);
    this.button.addEventListener('click', this.setState.bind(this));
    return this.button;
  }
  setState() {
    if (this.button.getAttribute('state') == 'pause') {
      this.button.setAttribute('state', 'play');
      this.play();
    } else {
      this.button.setAttribute('state', 'pause');
      this.pause();
    }
  }
  play() {
    console.log("play");
    // ...
  }
  pause() {
    console.log("pause");
    // ...
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  let button = new Button();
}
```

```css
.button {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: With this you're always setting up the add event to play, but never the pause event. You should set this.button.addEventListener in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in the constructor you're returning **this.button**;

The new keyword does the following things:

1. Creates a blank, plain JavaScript object;
2. Links (sets the constructor of) this object to another object;
3. Passes the newly created object from Step 1 as this context;
4. Returns this **if the function doesn't return an object**. *(Your case)*

The object (not null, false, 3.1415 or other primitive types) returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation process.)

Answer (score 0):

This solution modifies your class with:

- a `playing` property
- an `addListener` method
- a `togglePause` method

**`addListener` sets up a [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) version of `togglePause` to listen for button clicks.

`togglePause` toggles the "playing" state and does any additional on-click work.**

(And a `logState` method reports the state of the "playing" property.)
See the in-code comments for further clarifications.

```js
class Button {
  constructor() {
    this.button = document.createElement('div');
    this.button.className = 'button';
    document.body.appendChild(this.button);

    this.playing = true;
    this.addListener();

    // (Constructor returns the constructed object by default)
  }

  addListener() {
    // Calls the togglePause function on click, but uses `.bind` to 
    //   pass our custom object as the "this" context at click-time
    // (Otherwise, "this" would mean the html button element)
    const boundTogglePause = this.togglePause.bind(this);
    this.button.addEventListener('click', boundTogglePause);
    this.logState(); // Logs initial state
  }

  togglePause() {
    // `this.playing` is a Boolean, so `!` toggles its value
    this.playing = !this.playing;
    // The `play` and `pause` business logic could go here if it's simple,
    //   or we can call dedicated `play` and `pause` methods...
    if (this.playing){ this.play(); }
    else { this.pause(); }
    this.logState(); // Logs the newly changed state
  }

  logState() { console.log(this.playing ? "playing" : "paused"); }

  play(){ console.log("\nplay method called"); }
  pause(){ console.log("\npause method called"); }
}

window.onload = function() {
  const button = new Button();
}
```

```css
.button {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #000;
}
```